# Is there anyway to find out what type of View a View is?

Tags: android, view, childviews

So if I were to have a `LinearLayout` and had several children `Views` inside of it, say like a couple of `Buttons` a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`, using the `LinearLayout`'s `getChildAt(x)` I would then get an unspecified `View`. To note, I'm not using an xml in this so it's all done programatically.

```
public class CustomViewClass extends LinearLayout {

    private Context context;

    public CustomViewClass (Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        // Code which adds Buttons and such to the LinearLayout
        getChildAt(1)
    }

}
```

The `getChildAt(1)`, is there anyway that I can find out what kind of `View` it is, whether it's a `Button` or a `TextView` or whatever progamatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to call `getClass`. This will get you a `Class` object representing the type of view.

For example:

```
Class clazz = getChildAt(1).getClass();
```

After you have the class, you can do all kinds of things with it. e.g. get the name:

```
System.out.println(clazz.getName());
```

Now you know what kind of view it is.

Another way is to use the `instanceof` operator. Here's an example:

```
if (getChildAt(1) instanceof TexView) {
    // getChildAt(1) is a TextView or an instance of a subclass of TextView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instanceOf method. Sample example is

```
if (view instanceof ImageView)
```

Or You can use below to find out the type of view. But if you want to do any computation on it, instance of is the best choice.

```
view.getClass

if (view.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.ImageView"))
```